# React pass multiple data from child to parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to pass 2 values from a child component to the parent component in React. In the Child component, I call a parent function:

```
this.props.setparentcatidandlevel(this.props.catid, this.props.level);
```

The parent function is accessible by passing it as a prop to the Child:

```
<ShowProductsOfCat catid={props.match.params.catid} catname={props.match.params.catname}
level={props.match.params.level} setparentcatidandlevel={this.setparentcatidandlevel} />
```

In the Parent, the function is defined as follows:

```
    setparentcatidandlevel = (value1, value2) => {
        this.setState({
            catid: value1,
            level: value2
        }, () => {
            console.log('catid is now: ' + this.state.catid + ' and level is: ' + this.state.level)
        });
    }
```

But when I log both values to the console, the first parameter has correct value, but the second value is always NaN1111 or NaN111111111 or something even more elaborate.

Child:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import './styles/showprodofcat.css';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';

class ShowProductsOfCat extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            products: []
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.GetProductsOfCat();
        this.props.setparentcatidandlevel(this.props.catid, this.props.level);
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        if (this.props.catid !== prevProps.catid) { // prohibit infinite componentDidUpdate loop when state is updated
                                                    // in GetProductsOfCat()
            this.GetProductsOfCat();
            // call parent function with argument setting Parent state catid and level
            this.props.setparentcatidandlevel(this.props.catid, this.props.level);
        }
    }

    GetProductsOfCat() {
        fetch("https://categoriesexpress222.herokuapp.com/getproducts?CatID=" + this.props.catid)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(jsonresult => {
                this.setState({
                    products: jsonresult
                });
            });
    }

    render() {

        const productlist = React.Children.toArray(this.state.products.map((item) => // wrapped in React.Children.toArray in
            // order to automate unique 'key' generation
            <div className='indent' id='proditem'>
                <div id='prodname'>{item.productname}</div>
                <div id='description'>{item.description}</div>
                <div id='price'>€ {item.price}</div>
                <div id='image'><img src={this.getsrcPath(item.picture)} /></div>
                <div className='buttcont'>
                    <Link className='button' style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }} to={'/DeleteProduct/' + item.id +
                        '/' + item.productname + '/' + this.props.catid + '/' + this.props.catname + '/'}>Delete</Link>
                    <Link className='button' style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }} to={'/ProductDetails/' + item.id +
                        '/' + this.props.catid + '/' + this.props.catname}>Details</Link>
                </div>
                <br />
            </div>
        ))

        return (
            productlist ?
                <div>
                    <div id='catname'>
                        {this.props.catname}
                    </div>
                    <div className='singleproduct'>
                        {productlist}
                    </div>
                </div> : null // when there are no products, hide everything
        )
    }
}

export default withRouter(ShowProductsOfCat); // we use withRouter so that we can use history.push
```

Parent:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ShowProductsOfCat from './components/ShowProductsOfCat';
import './App.css';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';

class App extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            level: 1,
            catid: 0
        }
    }

    setparentcatidandlevel = (value1, value2) => {
        this.setState({
            catid: value1,
            level: value2
        }, () => {
            console.log('catid is now: ' + this.state.catid + ' and level is: ' + this.state.level)
        });
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <div>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <Switch>
                                    <Route exact path="/ShowProductsOfCat/:catid/:catname/:level" render={(props) => (
                                        <ShowProductsOfCat catid={props.match.params.catid} catname={props.match.params.catname}
                                            level={props.match.params.level} setparentcatidandlevel={setparentcatidandlevel}/>
                                    )} />
                        </Switch>
                        ...other components
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default withRouter(App);
```

Comment: What does the `Route` for `App` look like? Or for `ShowProductsOfCat`?

Comment: this.props.history.push('/ShowProductsOfCat/' + this.props.catid + '/' + this.props.catname + '/' + this.props.level);

Comment: I mean there are no `Route` in the `Switch`. Like `<Switch><Route path=...` and so on.

Comment: Yes there are routes. I have edited my post, they are there now.

Comment: Do you call `setparentcatidandlevel` from other places?